# How do I enable reboot in Windows 7 for Remote Desktop sessions when windows is not responding?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, remote-desktop

I tried to connect to a remote desktop via Windows Remote Desktop client for OS X, but the windows machine froze so no menus or keys are available. Therefore none of the other answers to similar questions are relevant.

How do I restart the remote machine? Quitting the program and reopening the connection does not work.

Note that I'm on OS X so I don't even have a delete key.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-alt-backspace functioned as ctrl-alt-delete. What a fluke.

Comment: Sounds like the machine didn't freeze then... If you were in a full-on freeze, you would need some kind of out of band management to reboot.

Comment: Understood, thanks. But keeping this question/post as I found nothing on rebooting using OS X.